# textarea doesn't update

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, textarea

With jQuery, I added a textarea

```
$('#description').append('<textarea rows="8" cols="40">test</textarea>');
```

Ok, and I change "test" text to "test 01".  But, when I try

```
 var cadena = $('#description').text();
 alert(cadena);
```

I get "test" and not "test 01".  Why?

Comment: How did you changed the text of `textarea`? Where is the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

give the `textarea` an id and then change it's value with the `val` function:

```
$('#description').append('<textarea id="xxx" rows="8" cols="40">test</textarea>');    
$('#xxx').val('test01');

//... later on
alert($('#xxx').val());
```

Comment: Perfect, I was using $("#myTextArea").html(''); and I might use $("#textoObs").val(''); and works!

Answer (score 8):

Like it says on the [`.text()` doco page](http://api.jquery.com/text/), "To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method."

You don't say how you change the text, but you should be doing this:

```
$('#description textarea').val("test 01");        // change the text

var cadena = $('#description textarea').val();   // retrieve the current text
```

Noting that "#description" is the textarea's container, and you need to select the textarea itself to get the value. Of course the above won't work if you have more than one textarea in that container, so it would be better if you could assign the new textarea an id an then select based on that.

Comment: `#description` isn't the `textarea` it is something that holds it.

Comment: Thanks @gdoron, yes, I'd noticed that and was editing my answer while you were posting the comment.

Answer (score 3):

It really looks like you would want to do this:

```
$('#description').append('<textarea id="newTextArea" rows="8" cols="40">test</textarea>');¬
```

And then this:

```
var cadena = $('#newTextArea').text();
alert(cadena);
```

Otherwise, you're just appending the `textarea` inside of whatever `#description` is, and then trying to get the `.text` value of...all that (whatever it is).

If you add an `id` to the `textarea`, you can be more specific with your selection, and get the text value that you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

User `.val()` instead of `.text()`.

If you have **only one text area** appended you can do

```
 var cadena = $('#description textarea:first-child').val();
```

Test Case : http://jsfiddle.net/UzK59/

OR

If you are appending **more than one text area**

```
 var counter = 0;
 $('#description').append('<textarea id="textArea'+ counter +'" rows="8" cols="40">test</textarea>');
 counter++;
```

and then

```
 $('#textArea' + counter).val(); //Considering counter is 0 (Zero) here
```

Test Case : http://jsfiddle.net/UzK59/1/

To set value you can do

```
 $('#textArea' + counter).val('New Value')
```

Hope this helps you.